# Website Critical Rendering Path Displays then disappears for 3 seconds

Tags: performance, mobile-website

I'm optimizing this website to load fast:https://alternativarife.com/

The critical rendering path is displayed in the first 2 seconds but then the screen goes blank for 3 seconds. I am not sure what could be causing the screen to blank out.

Answer (score 0):

Watching your site load under the `performance` tab in Google Chrome's `Developer Tools` shows that once the page is first painted, a call to Recalculate Style is done by `autopitimize_...js`. That is when everything disappears, then later another call to Recalculate Style from `autoptimize_...js` before everything is painted for the final time.

Turning off Javascript for your page makes it load instantly and never sees the content disappear. Autoptimize is doing a great job of de-optimizing your page.